# Elasticsearch Term suggester is not returning correct suggestions when one character is missing (instead of misspelling)

Tags: elasticsearch, spell-checking, elk, misspelling, term-suggester

I'm using `Elasticsearch term suggester` for spell correction. my index contains huge list of ads. Each ad has subject and body fields. I've found a problematic example for which the suggester is not suggesting correct suggestions.

I have lots of ads whose subject contains word "soffa" and also 5 ads whose subject contain word "sofa". Ideally, when I send "sofa" (wrong spelling) as text to suggester, it should return "soffa" (correct spelling) as suggestions (since soffa is correct spell and most of ads contains "soffa" and only few ads contains "sofa" (wrong spell)).

Here is my suggester query body :

```
{
  "suggest": {
    "text": "sofa",
    "subjectSuggester": {
      "term": {
        "field": "subject",
        "suggest_mode": "popular",
        "min_word_length": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I send above query, I get below response :

```
{
    "took": 6,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "suggest": {
        "subjectSuggester": [
            {
                "text": "sof",
                "offset": 0,
                "length": 4,
                "options": [
                    {
                        "text": "soff",
                        "score": 0.6666666,
                        "freq": 298
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "sol",
                        "score": 0.6666666,
                        "freq": 101
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "saf",
                        "score": 0.6666666,
                        "freq": 6
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As you see in above response, it returned "soff" but not "soffa" although I have lots of docs whose subject contains "soffa".

I even played with parameters like `suggest_mode` and `string_distance` but still no luck.

I also used `phrase suggester` instead of `term suggester` but still same. Here is my phrase suggester query :

```
{
    "suggest": {
        "text": "sofa",
        "subjectuggester": {
            "phrase": {
                "field": "subject",
                "size": 10,
                "gram_size": 3,
                "direct_generator": [
                    {
                        "field": "subject.trigram",
                        "suggest_mode": "always",
                        "min_word_length":1
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I somehow think it doesn't work when one character is missing instead of being misspelled. in the "soffa" example, one "f" is missing.
while it works fine for misspells e.g it works fine for "vovlo".
When I send "vovlo" it gives me "volvo".

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "string_distance".

```
{
  "suggest": {
    "text": "sof",
    "subjectSuggester": {
      "term": {
        "field": "title",
        "min_word_length":2,
        "string_distance":"ngram"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#term-suggester

Comment: tried, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I've found the workaround myself.
I added ngram filter and analyzer with `max_shingle_size` 3 which means trigram, then added a subfield with that analyzer (trigram) and performed suggester query on that field (instead of actual field) and it worked.

Here is the mapping changes :

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "shingle": {
                    "type": "shingle",
                    "min_shingle_size": 2,
                    "max_shingle_size": 3
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "trigram": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "shingle"
                    ],
                    "char_filter": [
                        "diacritical_marks_filter"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "subject": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "trigram": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "trigram"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my corrected query :

```
{
  "suggest": {
    "text": "sofa",
    "subjectSuggester": {
      "term": {
        "field": "subject.trigram",
        "suggest_mode": "popular",
        "min_word_length": 1,
        "string_distance": "ngram"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I'm performing suggester to `subject.trigram` instead of `subject` itself.

Here is the result :

```
{
    "suggest": {
        "subjectSuggester": [
            {
                "text": "sofa",
                "offset": 0,
                "length": 4,
                "options": [
                    {
                        "text": "soffa",
                        "score": 0.8,
                        "freq": 282
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "soffan",
                        "score": 0.6666666,
                        "freq": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "som",
                        "score": 0.625,
                        "freq": 102
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "sol",
                        "score": 0.625,
                        "freq": 82
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "sony",
                        "score": 0.625,
                        "freq": 50
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see above soffa appears as first suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There is sth weird in your result for the term suggester for the word `sofa`, take a look at the text that is being corrected:

```
"suggest": {
    "subjectSuggester": [
        {
            "text": "sof",
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 4,
            "options": [
                {
                    "text": "soff",
                    "score": 0.6666666,
                    "freq": 298
                },
                {
                    "text": "sol",
                    "score": 0.6666666,
                    "freq": 101
                },
                {
                    "text": "saf",
                    "score": 0.6666666,
                    "freq": 6
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see it's `sof` and not `sofa` which means the correction is not for `sofa` but instead it's for `sof`, so I doubt that this issue is related to the analyzer you were using on this field, especially when looking at the results `soff` instead of `soffa` it's removing the last `a`

Comment: @Code_Worm did you get the chance to check my answer? I'm curios to know weather I'm right or not